Is there a way in Stripe to check if an Event object caused from a Stripe automatic retry is it last try?
I'm trying to log in Sentry errors occurred in a flow that includes Stripe web-hooks but I only want to log those that are created automatically by Stripe when it retry failed web-hooks and only when is the last retry that Stripe is going to make.
Is there any field or way to know if is the last retry Stripe is going to make?

Unfortunately that's not possible. The retry behavior isn't really predictable and has different factors that can influence it. You can read more about the retries behavior here.

I've thought on setting a retries_left field onto the metadata of the Event and everytime I receive it, check if it is 0 and otherwise, substract one but I don't know if it is possible since I'm really a beginner in Stripe, do you think it can be done?
Thank you in advance.

You wouldn't really know as I mentioned the number of retries depends on so many factors.
